# Streaming custom objects

Tags: soap, jaxb, jax-ws, glassfish-3

I am building a SOAP webservice.  I am using JAX-WS to create this service and deploying it on a Glassfish 3.1.2 server.

I have no problem having this service return a String build with the XML representation of what I want.  I can also get it to return a specific object.  What I am having issues with is ***streaming*** this resource.

This is what I have so far :

**Interface** :

```java
@MTOM
@WebService
@XmlRootElement(name="root.element.class.location")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC, use=Use.LITERAL)
public interface ResultsServer {

    @WebMethod
    @XmlMimeType("text/xml")
    public Test getResultDataAsXML(@WebParam(name="Id") Integer id) throws Exception;
}
```

**Implementation** :

**---- Edit ----**

This is where I would like to stream my resource.  Let's say I need my `results` object becomes extremely large, I don't want to hold this is memory and would like to start sending it without holding it.  (commented this in code)

```java
@WebService(endpointInterface = "my.endpoint.class")
@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly=true, memoryThreshold=4000000L)
public class ResultsServerImpl implements ResultsServer {

    @Override 
    public Test getResultDataAsXML(Integer id) throws Exception {
        Test results = new Test();
        for(int i=0; i<[very large number]; i++) {
            results.getResults().add("here : " + i);
            /**at one point, this is too large to hold in memory
            I would like to be able to start returning the object here
            so it is not taking up all available memory */
        }
        return results; //or close the stream
    }
}
```

**---- End Edit ----**

And my `Test` class is a simple class looking like this :

```java
public class Test {

    private ArrayList<String> results;

    public Test() {
        results = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(ArrayList<String> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

Let's assume that this `Test` object becomes very big (and more complexe).  I need to be able to stream this object.  How would I go to proceed in streaming this.

Ideally, I would like to keep the structure of this object.

From what I have read so far, I would need to convert this object in some sort of `DataHandler` and return this object.

Any help is welcome!  Thank you.

Comment: The JAX-WS implementation will leverage a JAXB implementation to marshal the object (most likely to a StAX `XMLStreamWriter`) so the output will be streamed (there won't be an XML document created in memory).  Are you looking for a way to prevent the instance of `Test` from being fully realized in memory?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I think you've worded this the way I was looking for.  Yes that would be to prevent the instance of `Test` of fully being saved in memory.  Is there a way to do this?  Also: Thanks for the infor regarding JAXB marshaling.  This did answer a lot of the questions I've had.

Answer (score 0):

The JAX-WS implementation will leverage a JAXB implementation to marshal the object (most likely to a StAX XMLStreamWriter) so the output will be streamed (there won't be an XML document created in memory).

> @BlaiseDoughan I think you've worded this the way I was looking for.
>   Yes that would be to prevent the instance of Test of fully being saved
>   in memory. Is there a way to do this?

If you want the data to appear in the messages as XML (as opposed to a SOAP attachment), the you could leverage JAXB's marshal events.  In the `beforeMarshal` event you could load data into an object and then clear it in the `afterUnmarshal` method.  Ultimately all the data will be pulled in, but it won't all be referenced at the same time.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback

Comment: This seems like the process I want to take.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with using the marshal events.  I am looking into this.  Any usage examples you could provide in terms of using this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After working on this, my question is a bit more specifically : What object are you refering to that I would load my data into?  The `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller` both have their own `Listener`s, how is the data of this object transferred from one to the other?  Unfortunately, I think I might be missing a big piece of the puzzle here.

Comment: @blo0p3r - Into your domain model.

Comment: As a follow up question (forgive my lack of undestanding) : My server is sending information to a client.  Therefore, I never "Unmarshal" my XML on the server. `afterUnmarshal` is never called.  On top of that `beforeMarshal` and `afterMarshal` are only called when I'm returning the full object (ie: `return results` - in the implementation above).  I'm confused as to how setting any values in my domain model from these functions saves memory in my results object since before any of the marshal functions are called, it is fully created.

Comment: @blo0p3r - I misunderstood your comment then about preventing `Test` from fully being in memory.  I'm confused now what your question is.  If you are ok with `Test` being fully in memory and by default your `JAX-WS` impl will stream to XML (most likely via StAX) is your use case covered?

Comment: I have edited the question slightly to hopefully clarify this.  In my implementation example - I would like to say, add the `String` to the response without necessarily saving it to memory, within the `results` object.  The way it is shown now, works when the `results` object stays relatively small, but if grows larger then memory allows, it overflows.  I want to prevent this.  And again, real life senario would have it that the String is a more complex type - I have no problem converting this to XML using JAXB - that is not my problem.

Comment: https://www.java.net//node/680398 : Similar question here.  Different working (maybe better).  Unfortunately, I'm not sure the answers given in link aren't quite clear/functional/accurate.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the xstream (http://x-stream.github.io/) library from thoughtworks for your streaming as it is bindable on both sides of your service and is compatible with SOAP envelops. In fact there is even an integration with ActiveSOAP.

An example of a SOAP envelope wrapped xstream object can be seen at http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/19097/SoapEnvelopeTestCase.java. A full usage from jboss can be seen at https://issues.jboss.org/secure/attachment/12325534/SOAPClient.java?_sscc=t.

XStream has been used for some very large streaming processes (I've used it for some large 100+ MB text objects without issue).

Comment: Could whoever marked me down please give me a clue as to what you would rather see. I understand what this person is going through and most of the datahandler objects for SOAP when trying to get XML content are very complex and tend to have non-human readable formats. I'm suggesting a very good library that has a ton of power that for this. I'd be happy to change or remove my answer if needed but just voting me down does neither blo0p3r nor I any good. Thanks.

Comment: This is interesting.  I appreciate the suggestion (and also do think that whoever voted down should provide the reason as to why and suggest something better/different).  But this converts the object to an XML object.  This already happens.  What you're suggesting would be converting this object to a String, then streaming this String?  I'm also noticing that the types are being marked as `class="string"` instead of `xsi:type="xs:string"`.  Which I am assuming the latter would be better for compatibility with a .NET achitecture (receiving end in my case).

Comment: Actually it doesn't have to ever be a string as it can use the sTax based parser when you instantiate it (to be used for serialization) `XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());` and then when you grab the object you can stream it directly to an output stream via
http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#toXML(java.lang.Object, java.io.OutputStream).

Comment: As for reading from this on a .Net end-point I don't have experience here but I do know that there are a couple of libraries that will do it such as https://code.google.com/p/xstream-dot-net/.